# Need to inspect memoised package function for memoisation to work

Tags: r, memoization, memoise

Let's say I have a package with the following function:

```
foo <- function() {
  Sys.sleep(1) # really expensive operation
  return(1)
}
```

The value of the function is always the same per run, so I would like to use memoisation.

I thought I could simply do

```
foo <- memoise::memoise(function() {
  Sys.sleep(1) # really expensive operation
  return(1)
})
```

However, this doesn't work.

I mean, running it as a GlobalEnv function, it works:

```r
foo <- memoise::memoise(function() {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  return(1)
})

system.time(foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       1

system.time(foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.01    0.00    0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, if it's in a package, I get really weird behavior. Basically, memoisation doesn't kick in and I keep getting the same cost. However, if I print the function definition, it starts working!

```r
system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.47    0.08    2.55

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       2

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.02    0.00    2.02

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.01    0.00    2.02

bar::foo
#> Memoised Function:
#> function() {
#>   Sys.sleep(2)
#>   return (1)
#> }
#> <environment: namespace:bar>

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       2

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

system.time(bar::foo())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0
```

For the record, here are the relevant parts of the `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION` files:

```
# NAMESPACE
export(foo)
importFrom(memoise,memoise)

# DESCRIPTION [...]
Imports:
    memoise
```

What's going on here, and what should I do to make memoisation work from the start in my package?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the `memoise` package.  When you are working on your own package, R may add debug information (called `srcref`s) to functions.  Something about those cause the hash to come out differently every time you call the function, so it never recognizes that you are calling with the same arguments.

A simple workaround is to remove the install option "--with-keep.source" when you install your own package. (If you're using RStudio, this is added automatically in `Project Options | Build Tools | Install and Restart...` .) This will stop R from adding the `srcref`, and the bug in `memoise` won't be triggered.  Unfortunately, this cripples the debugger in RStudio and other front-ends, so it's not ideal.

Another workaround that doesn't mess with the debugger (except for that one function) is to use `removeSource` on the target that is being memoised.  For example,

```
foo <- memoise::memoise(removeSource(function() {
  Sys.sleep(1) # really expensive operation
  return(1)
}))
```

Comment: I just noticed something in the `?memoise` help page:  it recommends doing the memoization in `.onLoad`, not in the source.  That's probably another workaround.

Comment: Interestingly, the `memoise` Github has a [modified documentation](https://github.com/r-lib/memoise/blob/58d39726de141fefd235557a33e6478f76b0ad7f/R/memoise.R#L35) which suggests using `.onLoad` to perform the actual memoisation. The [reasoning for it](https://github.com/r-lib/memoise/issues/76) seems to be more related to build-time dependencies, though.